# WSO2 - IS 5.1.0.x. - Return formattedName in JWT Payload

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

How do I return attribute "name.formatted" in JWT payload?

Here is my claim configuration:

[image]

Here is the profile:

[image]

Now, Service Provider's claim config:

[image]

This is JWT payload:

[image]

Please note even if I enable formattedName as "Supported by Default" and add it to service provider's claims it doesn't be added to JWT. Other attributes such as "family_name" does.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a custom claim returned in the ID token, the claim needs to be mapped to an OIDC claim and added to the OIDC scope. You can refer to [1] to get to know how to do that.

[1] https://medium.com/@inthiraj1994/lets-add-a-custom-claim-to-oidc-in-wso2-is-d871e418d6b0

Comment: This is exactly what I need! In my case, I just added new claim called "formattedName" to http://wso2.org/oidc/claim, mapped to existing claim "http://wso2.org/claims/formattedName" and finally added it in service provider's configuration.